# Proving line equalities when you are given angle bisectors of a shape

Tags: geometry

**Question:**
In the figure shown, $B$ is on $AR$ and $C$ is on $AS$. The angle bisectors of $\angle{ABC}$ and $\angle{ACB}$ meet intersect at $I$. The angle bisectors of $\angle{CBR}$ and $\angle{BCS}$ meet at $E$. $M$ is the midpoint of $IE$. Show that $BM = CM$.

[image: Diagram described]

I am struggling to find in between the angle bisection and the proof of sides $BM$ and $CM$ being equal. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. $\angle EBI=\angle ECI=90^\circ$
2. $EBIC$ are points on a circle (inscribed quadrilateral), $IE$ is diameter, $M$ is the center of the circle
3. $MB$ is a radius and so is $MC$